# Google maps with jquery.mobile: how to correctly resize map canvas?

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

I am writing a jquery mobile app which needs a map.

For the map I am planning to use Google maps service.

To account for orientation changes, I tried to use something like:

```
<script>
$('#page-map').live('pagecreate', function(event) {
    var map = $('#map_canvas').gmap({
        ...
    });
    ...
    $(window).resize(function() {
       $('#map_canvas').width($(window).width());
       $('#map_canvas').height($(window).height());
    });
)};
</script>
```

The problem: this code correctly resizes the map canvas when the device is rotated, but it looks like jquery mobile resize() is skipped (the url bar is visible, for example...).

Not even adding to the "resize(function() {" code something like this:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

is of any help.

*UPDATE:*
The issue only happens on the only mobile device I'm testing my pages - a Samsung Galaxy Mini (GT-S5570), Android 2.3.4 (Gingerbread). It does *not* happen when resizing window on a desktop PC (i.e: on a desktop browser map_canvas is correctly filled when browser's window is enlarged, even without the resize() binding, only due to width/height at 100% on map_canvas...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assign a size through css to my map in jquery mobile

I add the map_canvas inside div with dimencion deuin want in this case 100%

CSS

```
#map_content {
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;}


#map_canvas {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
text-shadow: none;}
```

HTML

```
         <div data-role="content" id="map_content" data-theme="a">
            <div id="map_content">
                <div id="map_canvas"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: If you don't resize #map_canvas when window size changes (for example because device changes orientation from portrait to landscape), map will not be filled with geo data, leaving an empty stripe on the right of the window...

Comment: Sorry: do you use a mobile device? If so, the CSS if enough for you to refill the map_canvas when orientation changes (and live the url bar hidden)? If so, may I ask which is our device (iPhone/Blackberry/Android/...)?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the above answer (plus many others) and nothing worked for me. Actually, the above code was working for me, but just until I started using jQuery Mobile. Somehow, when I load jQuery Mobile (funnily enough, I noticed that it's the JS, no the CSS) the map_canvas has no height (a trick to check the height of the element is adding a border to it like `border: 1px solid red;`).

Eventually, I managed to solve the auto-resize when the orientation changes by using the following code/css:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageID">
   <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div id="map_canvas">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And in the css:

```
html,
body,
#pageID {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.ui-content {
  padding: 0;
}
.ui-content,
.ui-content #map_canvas {
  height: inherit; /* the trick */
}
```

So, basically the: `height: inherit;` solved the problem for me.

Credits: https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/content-div-height-css-solution/comment-page-1/#comment-250

I hope it helps!